# AWS ELB - Extract PKI distinguished name from client cert before proxying

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, pki

We use personal PKI certificates for authentication with a system. Right now, we use a layer 4 ELB and just let NGINX handle all the PKI-related tasks.

We're trying to move towards API Gateway/Lambda for some of our simpler services, but dropping our PKI authentication system is out of the question. Is there any way, using either Classic or Application ELB, to extract the DN of a PKI client certificate and set it as a custom HTTP header before proxying the request along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that with an ELB or ALB. You could setup TCP load balancing with a classic ELB and continue to handle the certificate validation on the backend servers.

Also, what does this have to do with your move to API Gateway and Lambda? You don't use load balancers with those services.

Comment: I guess you're right, we'd only need to configure DNS for that. Either way, I don't think I could even force an API Gateway to request a client specify their certificate.